# How to render ApexCharts stacked bar inside modal/v-dialog component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, apexcharts

I'm encountering a niggly issue with vue-apexcharts - while trying to display some data in a stacked bar plot.

I have a simple component defined as follows:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="this.loaded">
        <apexchart
            width="100%"
            :height="this.height"
            :options="this.chartOptions"
            :series="this.chartData"
        ></apexchart>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "StackedBar",
    props: ["data", "labels", "height"],

    data() {
        return {
            loaded: false,
            chartData: [],
            chartOptions: {},
        }
    },

    async mounted() {
        await this.$nextTick()
        this.chartData = this.data
        this.chartOptions = this.buildChartOptions()
        this.loaded = true
    },

    methods: {
        buildChartOptions: function () {
            let chartOptions = {
                theme: {
                    mode: this.getTheme(),
                },
                chart: {
                    fontFamily: "Roboto Mono, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif",
                    type: "bar",
                    stacked: true,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        horizontal: true,
                    },
                },
                xaxis: {
                    categories: this.labels,
                },
                fill: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "right",
                    horizontalAlign: "left",
                },
            }

            return chartOptions
        },

        getTheme: function () {
            if (this.$vuetify.theme.dark) {
                return "dark"
            } else {
                return "light"
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

This component is used in a vuetify `v-dialog` component, and only visible when a user clicks to expand the `v-dialog`'s parent component. Ignoring the `nextTick()` call in the mounted hook, which seems to be necessary to get the chart to render at the first visibility toggle of the dialog component, I see the following:

1. User clicks to expand component; dialog becomes visible. Chart is rendered as expected.
2. User clicks to close dialog. Dialog no longer visible.
3. User clicks to expand component; dialog becomes visible. Chart does not display, with the following error thrown:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at s.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at c (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at s.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:6)
    at t.value (apexcharts.min.js:14)
    at t.<anonymous> (apexcharts.min.js:6)
```

Interestingly, if I toggle the `stacked` option to `false`, this no longer happens, and chart is displayed as expected every time the dialog is opened/closed. This behaviour also doesn't happen if I display the data as a heatmap rather than a bar.

**So my question is:** is this an expected behaviour, and some operator on my end, or is this unexpected?

A stacked bar is really the most clear choice for the data I'm trying to display, and ApexCharts seems to be overwhelmingly superior to all other plotting libraries I've tried - so a solution would be wonderful.

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, turning data labels off seems to resolve the issue, which isn't ideal - but is workable for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put your component inside a `v-dialog`, did you add the `eager` prop to the dialog? The eager prop will force the components content to render on mounted.

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" eager>
   ...
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: Hmm, so this behaviour persists with the addition of the `eager` prop, only the first visibility state toggle produces a dialog with neither plot rendered. 

On second display, the plots render, and on third, I see the same error as above.

Comment: Having this exact issue, but not using Vue. Did you make any progress?

Comment: Having the same issue.

It's because a first value or an array is 0. And it's only when stacked is true.

Did you fin a solution for this?

test with fake numbers, it will work when you don't have any 0 as first value. I made an issue on their github: https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts/issues/407